# I try to make a discord bot that moves others when they deafen themselves

Tags: discord.py

that's the part of the code:

```
 async def on_voice_state_update(self,member,before,after):
     channel = (800674042247118878)
     if before.self.deaf and after.self_deaf:
        member.move_to = channel
```

and that's the error i get

```
File "C:\Users\nikos\Desktop\Koimisas\koimisas.py", line 14, in on_voice_state_update
    if before.self.deaf and after.self_deaf:
AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'self'
```

Comment: Why `.self.deaf` in one case and `.self_deaf` in the other? Don't you just want `.deaf` for both?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `after.deaf`

```py
async def on_voice_state_update(self,member,before,after):
     channel = self.bot.get_channel(800674042247118878)
     if after.deaf and after.channel:
        await member.move_to(channel)
```